# Query on XML column with space condition

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have table in that one column is XML column.

**Table1:**

```
Column1   Column2
1         XML value
```

Here I need to find the attribute values where it has leading spaces , for example .

This is the XML column [Column2 in the above table], here `BankAccountNumber` tag has leading space , so I need to write a query to find all the records in the table wherever it has leading spaces, could you please help me.

```
<PaymentMethodDetails>
    <EFtDetails>
        <routingNumber>5575776567</routingNumber>
        <BankAccountNumber>1234 </BankAccountNumber>
    </EFtDetails>
</PaymentMethodDetails>
```

Comment: Looks like a trailing space, not a leading space, please clarify. Are you checking just `BankAccountNumber` or all nodes? If so do you want all XML nodes shredded out into separate rows, or do you want the whole XML as one value?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I need to check the all the records whereever has a space at the end of Numbers in BankaccountNumber tag as mentioned above example. Here at the end of 1234 we have space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `starts-with` and `ends-with` functions. But we can get around that with `substring`

```sql
substring(., 1, 1) = " "
```

To look for a trailing space rather than a leading space, instead use

```sql
substring(., string-length(.), 1) = " "
```

To find any `BankAccountNumber` nodes starting with a space, you can use `exist`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Column2.exist('
  /PaymentMethodDetails/EFtDetails/BankAccountNumber/text()[substring(., string-length(.), 1) = " "]
') = 1;
```

To find *any* nodes starting with a space, you can use `//` to include all descendant nodes

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Column2.exist('
  //*[text()[substring(., string-length(.), 1) = " "]]
') = 1;
```

To actually shred the matching nodes into separate values, you can use a combination of `.nodes` and `.value`

```sql
SELECT
  x.nod.value('local-name(.)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
  x.nod.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY t1.Column2.nodes('
  //*[text()[substring(., string-length(.), 1) = " "]]
') x(nod);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6635a76683fa4e97463af8122e52738)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and your time, actually i need to find the space at the end of the numbers as shown in my example, like we have spaces at the end of 1234

Comment: So you use `substring(., string-length(.), 1) = " "` as shown